# pyttsx - Lang set

Tags: windows, python-2.7, text-to-speech, pyttsx

How do I set the lang to pt-br on pytts Windows? I tried to change it on operating system speech settings, but didn't work.

With the current lang(en) set it sounds robotic.

https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx/

P.S. I'm using Python 2.7( I can't update it, the current software I'm using only works with this version.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, switch your python version to 3.5 or better and use pyttsx3. It's faster but still has a robotic voice. You can adjust all kinds of settings in pyttsx3. If you want a less robotic voice, take some python tutorials, and do some research on some options out there.